# Blank Screen after update

Tags: updates

I did an update this morning and now I can't boot my laptop. I just keep getting a blank screen. I have no idea where to go with this.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you told us more, like what's your laptop make and model, graphics card, Ubuntu version etc.

Comment: Does anything appear before the blank screen? What color is the blank screen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the update broke your window manager.

Try to run in terminal mode by pressing `ctrl+alt+F1`, this should prompt you for a username and a password. 
Then you could try re-starting the windows manager by running something like `sudo service sddm restart` (this depends on the version of Ubuntu you're running, so it may be a different command).

Good luck!